How are these type of animations done?
The best way to describe it is, off screen animations? Im not sure what its called but i need to learn this animation style!


This was possibly made in After Effects. There are several ways to achieve this.

You could make a canvas that is much larger than your comp size, parent everything together and drag it all around

You could make a large canvas, place objects around it, then add a camera, and pan/track the camera around to move to the objects outside the original screen limits.

You could manually keyframe individual objects without parenting to move the objects around.


From the look of the animation, I'd guess the foreground objects are parented, but the background grid is keyframed manually.
You can learn how to make things like this by following this old (but good) tutorial on learning after effects
